# Out of Bounds Exception Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I looked at the code over and over but I can't seem to get rid of this error. What am I doing wrong? I'm getting an error at the line I bolded.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;

public class HW1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // The numbers for n are not relevant
        System.out.println("Please enter a number for the length of n.");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        // Creates an array with n values
        int[] vectorArray = new int[n];

        // Inputs random numbers into the array ranging from -100 to 100.
        int dummy;
        int temp = 0;

        // Loop to generate negative and positive numbers into the array
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

            dummy = (int)(Math.random()*2);
            if (dummy == 0) { 
                temp = -1; 
            } else {
                temp = 1; 
            } 

            **vectorArray[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*101)) * temp;**
            System.out.println(vectorArray[i]); }

        // Algorithm 1 - Brute force O(n^3)

        int max = -1;
        int sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your loop condition. The maximum index of your array can be `n - 1`. And you are accessing `nth` index.

Comment: Where is compiler error? Or why you used this tag?

Comment: `[0, n]` contains `n+1` element but your array has `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing position n+1 in the array which is out of bounds.
Try changing the following line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think its recommended to do something like this in case n ever changes after the array is initialized, and its more obvious what your code is doing (plus you'll never have to worry about this kind of Exception again):

`for (int i = 0; i < vectorArray.length; i++)`